# Finding set of vectors that spans the solution set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Question: Find a set of vectors $\{u,v\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ that spans the solution set of the equations:

$$\begin{align}w - x + y + z = 0 \\
5w + 2x - y + z = 0\end{align}$$

Reducing these I get:

When I reduce these, I'm getting

$x = -2z - 6w$

$y = -3z - 7w$

$z = u$

$w = v$

I am getting this as my answer:

$$(x,y,z,w) = u(-2,-3,1,0) + v(-6,-7,0,1)$$

But this is wrong for some reason and I don't understand what I did wrong. Could anyone help me solve this problem correctly?

EDIT: So apparently, the y and z values are correct, however I have my x and w values wrong somehow. According to my instructor, the first entry for u should be -1/7, however I'm not sure how to get that.

Comment: I got the same answer as you? Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: According to the online submission, the answer is wrong for some reason. I'm completely clueless on what could be wrong at this point since it makes perfect sense to me how you can conclude to that solution

Comment: Your answer looks correct to me. (Verified by plugging your answers into the original equations.) One thing I noticed is that you used the order $w,x,y,z$ in your equations but $x,y,z,w$ in your answer. Are you sure you are entering them into the online system in the order it expects?

Comment: I'm not sure if the online system is wrong. I can't see any other answer with that problem. From what I've understood in books, z = u and w = v. Hence my x, y are incorrect, but I don't see how

Answer (score -1):

I'll advance based on your calculations.

$$ (x,y,z,w) = ( -2u-6v, -3u-7v,u,v ) = ( -2u,-3u,u,0 )+ ( -6v,-7v,0,v )$$

> $$\implies (x,y,z,w) = u( -2,-3,1,0 ) + v( -6,-7,0,1 ). $$

Can you see your basis now?

Comment: I still don't see it. I thought I knew what I was doing for this problem but each time I try my answers keep being wrong

Comment: @Valrok: Make sure of your calculations. Double check your calculations for finding $x$ and $y$. As I said I solved based on your calculations.

Comment: According to my instructor, the x and w values are incorrect. Somehow the first value for u is -1/7 instead of -2 like both of us got.

Comment: @Valrok: You have two free variables and you are free how to choose them. In your case you chose $z$ and $w$.